# Print generic class type via toString()

Tags: java, generics

I just had a simple question in Java, if it was possible to print a generic class type in the toString method to show what datatype was being used for that class? If so how, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Like `obj.getClass().toString()`?

Comment: @paulsm4 I actually tried that before and got this error: non-static method getClass() cannot be referenced from a static context. Not really sure what to do been looking up online for awhile.